# Is it possible to show a tooltip in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to show a tooltip whenever user clicks an image in my app. I just want to know whether it is possible to show tooltip in an iOS app.

Answer (score 17):

There are a few ways you can do this, however I have had luck with the [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView) project. As far as tool tips go its a good fit for tutorials and similar events.

[image: Tooltip example]

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes that's what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html)

Since iOS 3.2 you can add your own menu items to the editing menu via the menuItems property.

Answer (score 1):

check this control [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover/), it is very useful

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up writing my own custom tooltip. It might be a solution for you.

You can init with your custom view (i assume you write some delegations to detect actions within.) and present from anywhere.

Maybe not the best replacement of UIPopoverController but still works great. And a lifesaver for iPhone. Also highly customisable.

https://github.com/akeara/AKETooltip

Hope this helps.