# Make UIMenuController Unselectable

Tags: objective-c, ios, uimenucontroller

I'm working on an iPhone app, and I want to use a tooltip. I've seen some questions about tooltips for iOS in the past ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9731371)) where the solution is to use something from cocoa controls, but I'm trying to avoid code I didn't write or don't understand.

Apple does precisely what I want to do in their Music app with a long press:

[image: Daft Punk seemed less likely to get me guff on SO]

This looks pretty clearly like a UIMenuController to me. Setting custom text of a UIMenuController has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079896). How does one stop the pop-up from being selectable?  I'm thinking Apple is just intercepting the touch event and dismissing it. That said, I don't know how they're doing that.

Currently, I'm leaving the menu item selectable with an action that is a blank method like so:

```
UIMenuItem *moreInfo = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:text
                                                  action:@selector(doNothing)];
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to either:

- intercept the touch event to prevent selection
- accomplish this goal through a completely different means

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the action to nil?

Comment: @RyanPoolos nope I'll try that now

Comment: @RyanPoolos you can still select the menuItem, and if you do it throws an 'NSInvalidArgumentException' :(

Comment: can you just do `setUserInteractionEnabled = NO`?

Comment: @TinCan Just a thought. Sorry it didn't work.

Comment: @iBlue nope - unrecognized selector - even tried performSelector to get around the compile error. no luck

Comment: @RyanPoolos no worries, thanks for the suggestion! I'm glad to be trying new ideas